# Add column flagging existence in another data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

Lets say I have a data frame with IDs and other columns and I want to add a column showing whether or not an ID also exists in another data frame.  If it does, the column should be a 1.  If it doesn't, it should be a 0.

How can I do this using `dplyr`? I've played around using `left_join`s as well as `mutate` and `ifelse` but can't seem to find a quick solution.

Comment: `as.numeric(id %in% otherDataframe$column)` perhaps, but we really would like a reproducible example

Comment: Hi Richard, that works.  Thanks!  Sorry i am new to posting to this site so I am not sure what the etiquette is yet.  Let me know if I should add to my question for others who might have a similar question.

Comment: This is a pretty good guideline to follow ;) http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask